How to use resourceTimeGridDay in drupal controller using fullcalendar block?
I'm trying to add the premium 'resourceTimeGridDay' full calendar to my drupal page. regular calendar grids work, but the resourcetimegridday does not work.

Uncaught Error: viewType "resourceTimeGridDay" is not available. Please make sure you've loaded all neccessary plugins

error message
to load the plugin properly I've tried adding various libraries from unpkg to the full calendar block module directly
`
libraries.fullcalendar_resource:
  header: true
  js:
    https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource #:{type: external, attributes:{async:true}}
libraries.fullcalendar_resource_timegrid:
  header: true
  js:
    https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid #:{type: external, attributes:{async:true}}
libraries.fullcalendar_scheduler:
  header: true
  js:
    https://unpkg.com/fullcalendar-scheduler #:{type: external, attributes:{async:true}}

`
This doesn't seem to resolve my problem.
This is the controller code where I am injecting the full calendar block. if you replace 'resourceTimeGridDay' with 'timeGridWeek' the calendar shows on the page. otherwise there is no calendar.
`
$block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
$config = [
  'event_source' => $url,
  'use_token' => TRUE,
  'initial_view' => 'resourceTimeGridDay',
  'header_start' => 'prev,next today',
  'header_center' => 'title',
  'header_end' => '',
  'open_dialog' => 1,
  'advanced' => '',
  'advanced_drupal' => '',
  'resources'=>[],
  'plugins' => ['rrule','moment'],
];

$plugin_block = $block_manager->createInstance('fullcalendar_block', $config);
$render = $plugin_block->build();
$build['full_calendar'] = $render;
return $build;`


I just attached the full calendar as separate library and wrote a small js handler and sent the variables in from the controller. I didn't bother with any of the contrib modules.
